# How to enable mobile network( 3G/4G ) in iOS by program?

Tags: ios

I am developing in iOS. I want to Enable mobile network( 3G/4G ) by program:

Does it need to JB ?

How to enable mobile network( 3G/4G ) in iOS by program ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this cannot be done without Jailbreak. iOS apps are sandboxed so you cannot access these settings via program.

I suggest you to check what is the connection type(3G 0r 4G) using CoreTelephony framework and prompt an alert to the user to switch to the desired mobile network.